# Reference cursor in Oracle Sql Developer

Tags: stored-procedures, cursor, oracle-sqldeveloper

I need to write a reference cursor in Oracle SQL developer and I have no clue how its written. I just know basic queries.

I have written following cursor to best of my knowledge after looking up into various example. I am getting an compile error "Missing or Invalid option".

Can anyone help me out?

Step 1: I created a new procedure in Oracle sql developer version 4. 
Step 2: I wrote the following cursor

```
DECLARE
routeid  VARCHAR2(10);
cursor     c1 IS
SELECT shipment_id FROM SHIPMENT
WHERE shipment_id = 20;

BEGIN
OPEN c1;
 LOOP
   FETCH c1 INTO routeid;
   EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;
   DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(routeid);
 END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Thank you in advance for the help.

Comment: perfect no error while execution what the problem ?

Comment: There was an issue with SQL developer. Its sorted.

Comment: @Sanjay: Can tell me how can I count number of rows returned from the cursor? Is there anyway I can do rowcount with DBMS_OUTPUT? If yes, how can I do that? I want to count the number of rows returned from the query and display it using DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE

Comment: you can not directly count rows from ref cursor you want to create on variable and increment by loop iteration that give you row count.

Comment: @sanjayradadiya: Need some expert advice: As you see in my answer I got the result into c1_rec. Now my next issue is, I want this cursor to have out parameter and value of each row should be saved in this out parameter. so for example,c1_rec.p_id should be moved into out parameter of that corresponding value...does this makes sense? is there any sample on how to do that?

Comment: For example: After EXIT when c1%NOTFOUND,  I want to have something like select c1_rec.p_id into Out_Pid?

Comment: add out parameter in procedure and assign c1_rec.p_id into out parameter variable.

Comment: I already added out parameter at the top of the procedure but how do I assisgn? whats the syntax? is simple Out_Pid  = c1_rec.p_id ?

Comment: Thanks @sanjayradadiya for the hint. understood how to assign. I have edited the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Better way to do simple cursor**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Test_cursor (Out_Pid OUT VARCHAR2) AS 
cursor  c1 IS
SELECT shipment_id,p_id FROM test
WHERE shipment_id = 99;

c1_rec c1%rowtype;

BEGIN
 OPEN c1;
  LOOP
  FETCH c1 INTO c1_rec;
  EXIT WHEN c1%NOTFOUND;

  Out_Pid := c1_rec.p_id;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Result from query '||c1_rec.p_id );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Result from out parameter '||Out_Pid );
 END LOOP;

  END Test_cursor;
```